# Does each item in a list comprehension get resolved as the list is constructed?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have the following line in my code:

```
processed = [singleRun.postProcess() for singleRun in simObjects if singleRun._ran]
```

The `postProcess()` function takes a few seconds to run per `simObject`, and in that time more of the `simObjects` might have their `._ran` attribute become `True`

_ran is an @property of the simObjects class, it can change as a result of actions outside of the scope of this script.

Is `postProcess()` run as each object is iterated over from the simObjects list and passes the if statement, or is the list of what will be `postProcess()`'d generated and *then* evaluated?

Full disclosure (that I realize now is pretty important): the script is submitting computational jobs to a distributed computing system and checking a file to see when they are done (via the @property, `._ran`), so the reason for the question is that either the list is generated of what is `_ran` first, or each object is `postProcess()`'d as it is iterated over in the list (and found to be `_ran`).

Comment: "The postProcess() function takes a few seconds to run per simObject, and in that time more of the simObjects might have their ._ran attribute become True" - Only if you are using multiple threads or processes, and then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: _.ran is a @property of the simObjects, so, is your (@Lennart Regebro) still statement correct?

Comment: If `._ran` changes on one object because you run `.postProcess()` on another object, you should strongly rethink your object architecture.

Comment: It does not, but the state of `._ran` is outside of the control of the program at hand. This statement is in a while loop that `postProcess()`s each object as it finds them to be `._ran`.

Comment: "It does not, but the state of ._ran is outside of the control of the program at hand." - So there is multiple processes going on then. ;-)

Comment: "the script is submitting computational jobs to a distributed computing system" - Well, first of all then, you should keep a list of jobs and only loop over those which have not yet been run and processed. You might want to use some sort of Queue implementation.

Comment: Aha, I suppose that is true :P. Why exactly would that be 'doing it wrong', though? The distributed computational stuff can take between 5 minutes and an hour, and I don't see a need to wait for them all to finish before post processing.

Comment: No, but you also don't need to sit and check if the post-processed ones are run or not. I'd probably just have a method that submits, wait for a response and the processes, for one job, and then start a thread per job. Unless you have hundreds of them. And unless the checking if it's done requires heavy polling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`postProcess()` is run as each object is iterated.
You could change that behavior to first make a list, based on `singleRun._ran` using lambda and then process the list again, running the filtered items.

Essentially you could:

```
filtered = [singleRun.postProcess for singleRun in simObjects if singleRun._ran]
processed = [item() for item in filtered]
```

This will first form a list `filtered` without a delay and then process it, without checking `singleRun._ran` if that's what you're aiming to do.

Comment: You were able to read through the muck of my poorly worded question (now edited) to find out what I was actually asking, hooray :]

Comment: The idea is there, but you will call the `postProcess` of method of the last item in filtered `len(filtered)` times. `singleRun` is a closure to the lambda that changes each iteration. Compare `[i.__pos__ for i in range(10)]` with `[(lambda: +i)  for i in range(10)]` as values for `filtered`. Since `postProcess` is a method you can just use that rather than creating a lambda.

Comment: @Dunes I am not sure, you could be right, perhaps this would change if I enclosed `lambda` in brackets. But your edit does the job all the same, without need for lambda.
(edit) Never mind, brackets don't change a thing, I am a python beginner myself, I was not aware of that behavior.

Comment: @Rusty Enclosing in brackets won't help. I wrote a little code snippet that expands the comprehensions into the actual for loop that is run, to try and explain why the lambda doesn't work. http://ideone.com/RQahA5

Comment: @Dunes I checked it out and it seems weird to me. It doesn't `feel` like it should work that way. When I enclose a loop variable in a closure I would want to get the object itself, not the reference to the variable of for-loop. I understand how it works now, I just don't understand why :\

Comment: It has to do with when the name lookup happens; the closure holds a reference to the local namespace the for loop ran in. You can however do `[lambda v=i: v for i in range(10)]` since the default value is held as an object reference, not an expression.

Answer (score 3):

`postProcess()` is called once if the condition (`if singleRun._ran`) evaluates to True.
You can test the behavior of list compression with the following dummy test:

```
def foo():
    print 'foo'

test = [foo() for f in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] if f % 2 == 0]
```

"foo" will be printed only twice, because in the list there are only 2 even numbers.

or with instances:

```
class Foo(object):
    def m(self):
        print 'm called'

objects = [Foo(), Foo(), Foo(), Foo(), Foo()]
x = [obj.m() for i, obj in enumerate(objects) if i % 2 == 0]
```

The same lazy approach is applied by Python when you write a "pseudo ternary operator" (honestly I don't know if it has a special name in Python) expression like:

```
foo() if condition else bar()
```

In this case foo() is called only if condition is true, despite the fact that it comes first... Python is smart enough to avoid extra computation if not necessary ;)

Comment: I know it's only called once, but perhaps I failed to mention an important part, `_ran` is an @property of the objects that checks a file outside of the scope of the code at hand, so it is (I believe) evaluated when the condition is checked, but are all the items in the list checked before `postProcess()` is evaluated?

Comment: @pixels No, check my answer for details.

Answer (score 2):

The decision is performed per iteration, not preallocated as an array of condition masks. In [list displays](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#list-displays), it is stated that "the elements of the new list are those that would be produced by considering each of the for or if clauses a block, nesting from left to right, and evaluating the expression to produce a list element each time the innermost block is reached."

In other words, your code:

```
processed = [singleRun.postProcess() for singleRun in simObjects if singleRun._ran]
```

Is functionally similar to:

```
processed = []
for singleRun in simObjects:
    if singleRun._ran:
        processed.append(singleRun.postProcess())
```

This means that if `_ran` changes for a later entry while `postProcess` is running, that change will cause another `postProcess` call. The main difference between the two forms of the code are that the name `processed` only binds to the list after it is finished in the first variant (and, like `map`, it might preallocate the list instead of resizing it repeatedly).